# Remove similar character string duplicates from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have df which currently looks something like this:

```
Car Name      Number
Adam Leaf     9
Adamm Leaf    9
Adam Lea      NaN
Adam-Leaf     NaN
Adam/Leaf     9
Claire-Green  NaN
Cliare Green  3
Claire Green  3
Claire Gren   NaN
Claire/Green  3
```

I am trying to remove the variations to achieve something like this

```
Car Name      Number
Adam Leaf     9
Claire Green  3
```

Comment: Why did you mark `r` and `python`? Try to be more specific.
Also you have to be more precise and explain what you mean by similar names.

Comment: Similar names meaning names which are incorrect variants i.e (an extra letter, extra symbols, letters missing etc)

Comment: Do fuzzy matching on your entries. [Documentation here](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/0.3.0/). Review the results checking which threshold you'll use to tag as "incorrect variants" and retain 1 to create your desired dataframe output.

Answer (score 3):

here is one way from `jellyfish`

```
import jellyfish

s=df.groupby(df['Car Name'].apply(jellyfish.soundex)).first()
              Car Name  Number
Car Name                      
A354         Adam Leaf     9.0
C462      Claire-Green     3.0
```

Comment: Cool package name!

Comment: This gives the correct car number, however it seems it's only selecting the first variant of the name

Comment: TIL `python jellyfish`

Comment: Avoid using groupby functions as that would result in full shuffling of the data before applying group by function. Try reduceByKey or similar instead.